# Dataset is missing the batch method in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Error message saying there is no attribute 'batch'

[image: 1]

I was trying to batch some pieces of data and received an error message.

I tried to upgrade my version of Tensorflow and then I re-ran everything but I still received an the same error. How can I get the batch method to be available?

Answer (score 1):

I used `split = 'train'` instead of `split = ['train']`. This allowed me to access the batch() method.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `list` has no `batch` function.
maybe you convert `train_ds` from some type that has `batch` function...

Comment: What datatype should I convert it to?